# Find all possible combinations of string with mysql

Tags: mysql, string, search

Is it possible to use mysql to search for the word "arsech" and find the word "Search" (if it is in the database)?

Comment: How would you want it to cope with dog/god ?

Comment: If you search for "dog", even "god" should be found.

Answer (score 0):

is a word contains both a and r and s and e and c and h, and doesn't contains the rest of the ABC... than you'll find all permutations... there is a problem with words that contain them more then once, but this also can be dealt with...

Answer (score 0):

[Checking for string permutation](http://planet.mysql.com/entry/?id=23103) describes this by normalizing the string.

BTW what problem does it solve?